# Serializing and deserializing data - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, serialization

I need to perform a lot of serializing and de-serializing in an application.

The data is **POST parameters** and **Cookie headers**.

---

Post data example:

> **Name**=Jonathan+Doe&**Age**=23&**Formula**=a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+13%25%21

Set-Cookie data example:

> **ASP.NET_SessionId**=esur3bqqgrmnci45um4xegye; **path**=/

---

Does anyone have any fast libraries to suggest or efficient ways to perform these operations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json.stringify

Comment: @David: can you explain please? :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a JSON stringify method:

http://zumbrunn.com/mochazone/JSON.stringify+and+JSON.parse/

JSON is a fairly universal serialization format that you can parse in ASP.Net. Basically it converts a JS object into a string of text that represents the object itself (as if you were to type the object declaration out literally).